# Absolute value proof using triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Proof verification:

Let F be any ordered field with $a,b,c \in F$, prove that $|a-c| \leq |a-b|+|c-b|$

Attempt:

$|(a-b)+(b-c)| \leq |a-b|+|b-c|$ by triangle inequality

$\implies |a-c|\leq |a-b|+|c-b|$ since $|b-c|=|(-1)(c-b)|=|c-b|$

Can I get a proof verification?

Comment: This proof is correct

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
|a-c|&=|(a-b)+(b-c)| \\
& \leq |a-b|+|b-c| \qquad (\textrm{by triangle inequality})\\
&= |a-b|+|c-b| \qquad (\textrm{since } |b-c|=|c-b|)
\end{align}$$
Maybe it helps a little in arranging things, or to present the proof. Either way, you're right.